# Cannot start second bounty on question with great answer

Tags: support, bounty

My question pertains to my question here: [Is it possible to characterize completeness of a normed vector space by convergence of Neumann series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552990/is-it-possible-to-characterize-completeness-of-a-normed-vector-space-by-converge/1892323#1892323)

First myself and then another user tried to increase the awareness this question received by offering bounties. The last user offered 500 reputation points, which seems to be the maximum.

Now, I would like to also offer 500 of my reputation points to the great answer the question finally received. However, I cannot do so, apparently because the "bounty amount" is required to be strictly increasing.

Is there any way in which I can reward that answer (in addition to upvoting and accepting)?

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot? Did you try and it failed? You should have been able to do this. If not, it'd be a bug. (You cannot do so now since I placed a bounty to test. But still please answer my query, whether you tried beforehand, as soon as possible.)

Comment: @quid: Yes, I tried, in the sense that I looked for the "start a bounty" button and did not find it at its usual position. I even Ctrl + f-ed for "bount". But maybe I was just VERY stupid... I will try again once your bounty expires.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification. I will award my bounty as soon as possible (which is  after the minimum wait of a day). Then I'll let you know if I could place a second one, and you could also try again.

Comment: I just awarded the bounty. Differently than for you I **would** be able to start another too. The "start a bounty" reappeared right away, when I click it I get the usual drop down; the points now start at 100, in line with the doubling restriction. Could you please check again if the "start a bounty" is still not present for you?  As you likely know, on the full view, it is written in black right below the "add a comment" for the *question* post. If you still cannot see it, maybe add browser/OS info. Also could you check if you see it on other questions eligible for bounty (ie not too new)?

Comment: I also see it in mobile view. Then it is right below the post in the same line as  share|edi|close|flag.

Comment: @quid: Thank you very much, now it works without problems. I probably made some really stupid mistake/was very blind.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I am glad your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, you should be able to place the bounty. For two reasons.

This is what the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) says (my emphasis):

> Additionally, if **you** offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

*You* offered only 150 and thus 300 should suffice in this case. But, actually, there is a missing detail there.

This is what the [relevant MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/16067/) says (my emphasis):

> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have at most 3 concurrent bounties at a time.
>
> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can **still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like** (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

Thus, offering a new 500 should be possible, regardless of earlier bounties on the question.

If you had tried and it failed it'd seem to be a bug.